# Grub ubuntu which is on a different ssd

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

I have two ssd installed in laptop, PNY for windows and Adata for ubuntu.  when I installed Ubuntu I made sure to install the grub loader on the adata ssd but when done, the grub loader instead got installed on the pny along with windows.

[image]

when i select ubuntu (P1 : Adata su 650) i got this

[image]

but when I select ubuntu (P0: PNY cs900) I can successfully login to ubuntu.

how to make ubuntu grub in Adata and how to delete ubuntu in PNY?

Comment: Be aware of bug 1396379 --Grub wrong disk https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379  Add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list, and see the fixes/workarounds for the bug. Each bootable device may have its own EFI partition, so if removed to another machine, it may still boot (with any expected driver problems if machines are too different).

Comment: Do you have an ESP - efi system partition on adata drive? Choice of boot loader location does not work with UEFI as per bug. It does work for BIOS. If you have ESP or create one with gparted then you can edit fstab with adata's ESP's UUID (make sure system sees change, may need reboot) and reinstall grub. `sudo grub-install` That reads UUID of ESP in fstab and in UEFI mode reinstall using that ESP.